# What is the difference between probability theory and possibility theory?

Tags: probability-theory, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

This question I encountered when I was solving theoretical probability question. It was harder for me to find the exact difference between both. I guess some fuzzy logic term are also involved.

If anyone knows or wants to give their views on it are welcome.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The difference seems pretty clear looking at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possibility_theory) and comparing the list of axioms to the probability axioms.